# Category.php=>Next Page Opens Index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have category.php file that and it works fine when we open a category link.
But in the category.php, when I click on "Next Page" link, it opens the index.php instead of next page of category.php .
Here is a little of my category.php code:

```
<?php
if (is_category( )) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
    $CAT=$yourcat->slug;
} ?>
<?php query_posts("category_name=$CAT&showposts=1&order=ASC"); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
.
.
.
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```

And index.php code:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=new_publish'); ?> <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
.
.
.
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: You don't need a custom loop in category.php

Comment: OK. Just deleted line 2 to 5 and category_name=$CAT. no diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this part of the code altogether. You don't need a custom loop on the category.php template.

```
if (is_category( )) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
    $CAT=$yourcat->slug;
} ?>
<?php query_posts("category_name=$CAT&showposts=1&order=ASC"); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I must increase my knowledge about wordpress ASAP :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi use like this this may work for you

```
<?php
if (is_category( )) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $yourcat = get_category ($cat);
    $CAT=$yourcat->slug;
} ?>
<?php $pos_loop = query_posts('post_type' => "post","category_name"=>$CAT,"order"=>"ASC","orderby"=>"date"); ?>
<?php while ($pos_loop -> have_posts()) : $pos_loop -> the_post(); ?>
.
.
.
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
```